# Use llvm 3.3 bitcode on LLVM 3.6 Static Pass

Tags: clang, llvm, compatibility, analysis, bitcode

Right now, I have an llvm bitcode compatible with llvm 3.3. However, my LLVM static pass is using llvm 3.6. Since the format of bitcode changes from 3.3 to 3.6, the pass is having issues on extracting debugging metadata. 
One way to solve this is that I could downgrade my whole llvm 3.6 pass to 3.3. However, is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: can you show your effort?

Comment: generally speaking, no. but sometimes you may have luck by disassembling bitcoin into IR (text format) and do some minor changes.

Comment: from 3.3 to 3.6 you will get into some trouble when you go through the readable IR because attribute handling, metadata and some instructions have changed during the versions of LLVM. Who produces the LLVM IR? maybe you can hoist it to 3.6?